# Disabling submit button until multiple checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I would like to disable a form submit button until 4 checkboxes are checked. I created a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CPFns/47) to represent my code that is not working as expected.

Here is my JS:

```
$(function() {
  $("#question1, #question2, #question3, #question4").change(function() {
    if( $("#question1").checked && $("#question2").checked && $("#question3").checked &&       $("#question4").checked ) {
      $('.next_button').disabled = false; 
    }
    else {
      $('.next_button').disabled = true;
    }
  });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<input id="question1" name="question1" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input id="question2" name="question2" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input id="question3" name="question3" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input id="question4" name="question4" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input class="next_button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Next" disabled="">
```

I am missing something simple here.  Appreciate any thoughts!

Comment: Hm..would you mind explaining the down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues here.

First, `.checked` is a Javascript attribute so using it on jQuery object wouldn't work. You will need to use jQuery's `.is(':checked')` call instead.

Second, on the JSFiddle you posted, you were using jQuery version 1.4.4, which didn't have `.prop()` support for the `disabled` attribute, thus you will need to use the `attr()` function to toggle the `disabled` state, instead.

See the updated function below:

```
$(function () {
    $("#question1, #question2, #question3, #question4").change(function () {
        if ($("#question1").is(':checked') && 
            $("#question2").is(':checked') && 
            $("#question3").is(':checked') && 
            $("#question4").is(':checked') ) {
            $('.next_button').attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('.next_button').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });

});
```

Working code at: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jEYSP/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function() {
   $("#question1, #question2, #question3, #question4").on( 'change', function() {

         $('button.next_button').prop( 'disabled', $(':checkbox:checked').length === 4);

   });
});
```

Comment: way awesome answer , great example of if I look at this confusing/hard problem differently is the solution actually easy .

Answer (score 1):

You have used old jQuery version 1.4 in Fiddle demo, so new function will not work properly
please try this way..

```
  $(function() {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").bind("click", function(e){
            if($("input[type=checkbox]").serializeArray().length == 
$("input[type=checkbox]").length){
               $(".next_button").removeAttr('disabled');
            }else{
                $(".next_button").attr('disabled', "disabled");
            }

        })
    });
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CPFns/52/)

I would preferred single selector e.g. class, element type instead of repeated ids of all elements

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$('.next_button').disabled = false;`, try using `$('.next_button').prop("disabled", false);` - likewise for setting it true. Some properties are removed, not set to false, so using the prop syntax will handle this for you.

Comment: Thanks. Tried this in the jsfiddle and doesn't seem to work - the 'next' button still remains disabled after I check all 4 checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(function() {
   $(':checkbox').on( 'change', function() {
      if( $(':checkbox:checked').length === 4 ) {
         $('input.next_button').prop( 'disabled', false );
      } else {
         $('input.next_button').prop( 'disabled', true );
      }
   });
});
```

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LsNqW/)

Comment: Thanks.  Tried this in the jsfiddle and doesn't seem to work - the 'next' button still remains disabled after I check all 4 checkboxes.

Comment: It's updated now. Check it out. It works. I had used button.next_button instead of input.next_button. My bad!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
$(function() {
$("#question1, #question2, #question3, #question4").change(function() {

if( $('#question1').attr('checked') && $('#question2').attr('checked') &&    $('#question3').attr('checked') && $('#question4').attr('checked') ) {
     $('.next_button').removeAttr('disabled');
}
else {
    $('.next_button').attr('disabled','disabled');

}
});


});
```

Here is the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/CPFns/51/

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CPFns/50/)

Here is what I have changed in your code:

```
$(function() {  $("#question1, #question2, #question3, #question4").change(function() {

if( $("#question1").attr('checked') && $("#question2").attr('checked') && $("#question3").attr('checked') && $("#question4").attr('checked') ) {
  $('.next_button').attr("disabled",false); 
}
else {
  $('.next_button').attr("disabled",true);     }  });});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length >= 4){
            $('.next_button').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else{
            $('.next_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name^=question]").change(function (e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        var toDisabled = (4 !== $("input[name^=question]:checked").length);
        $(".next_button").prop('disabled', toDisabled);
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xd3vE/)